# Adobe Xd: placing linked objects

Tags: creative-cloud, digital, adobe-xd, adobe-creative-suite, file-placing

I've recently started getting to grips with Adobe Xd, which seems great apart from the fact that I can't find a way to place linked objects in the same way that I can with Ps / Ai / Id

I'd like it so that, when I edit the object externally (e.g. using Illustrator) for it to them update in Xd, either automatically or by hitting an 'update' button.

Is this possible in Xd? Or do I need to re-import the object each time it is updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update a linked component, the way I know is to save it in your CC library and import it inside your XD project, and when you need to edit the component you edit the CC library object, and then you save the component, in PS or AI, the component in XD will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Billy commented, if you want to edit a photo in PS, you can right-click the image layer and select "Edit in adobe photoshop."

Good luck!